# Как лучше отрефакторить switch и массу case'ов с кучей кода в них?

Tags: c#, switch, рефакторинг

Текущий код (PerformTask() уже на 200 строк и типы заданий будут добавляться дальше):

```cs
public class Pawn
{
    public Task task;

    public void PerformTask()
    {
        switch (task.Type)
        {
            case TaskType.GatherResource:
                ...
                break;

            case TaskType.GetResourceFromBuilding:
                ...
                break;

            case TaskType.SupplyBuildingStub:
                ...
                break;

                ...

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Task
{
    public TaskType Type { get; set; }

    ...

    public enum TaskType
    {
        Undefined,
        GatherResource,
        GetResourceFromBuilding,
        SupplyBuildingStub
    }
}
```

Разбить на отдельные методы? Пример:

```cs
public class Pawn
{
    public Task task;

    public void PerformTask()
    {
        switch (task.Type)
        {
            case TaskType.GatherResource:
                GatherResource();
                break;

            case TaskType.GetResourceFromBuilding:
                GetResourceFromBuilding();
                break;

            case TaskType.SupplyBuildingStub:
                SupplyBuildingStub();
                break;

                ...

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    void GatherResource()
    {...}
    void GetResourceFromBuilding()
    {...}
    void SupplyBuildingStub()
    {...}
}
```

Или лучше вынести в класс TaskPerformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попытаться создать для каждого типа задачи отдельный класс: `GatherResourceTask`, `GetResourceTask`, etc (т.е. каждый класс будет отвечать за реализацию конкретного типа). Они будут унаследованы от какого-то базового класса или реализовать интерфейс, например:

```
interface ITask
{
    void PerformTask();
}
```

```
class GatherResourceTask : ITask
{
    public void PerformTask() { ... }
}
```

```
class Pawn
{
    public ITask Task { get; set; }

    public void PerformTask()
    {
        this.Task.PerformTask();
    }
}
```

В `Pawn` создавать `ITask`, а не `Task`, тогда в зависимости какая реализация будет подставлена в `Pawn`, будет разный код работать. Также, новые типы тасков довольно легко добавлять, создать новый класс и написать код, который будет создавать/подставлять этот `Task` в `Pawn` (т.е. минимальные изменения в текущем).

Answer (score 3):

```
Dictionary<TaskType, Action> actions = new ...;
actions[TaskType.GatherResource] = GatherResource;
actions[TaskType.GetResourceFromBuilding] = () => {...};

...

if (actions.ContainsKey(task.Type))
  action[task.Type]();
```